# How to apply strict pattern matching for title names in compton config file?

Tags: compton

I have a pretty simple config file for compton, just to set my terminal opacity.

`opacity-rule = ["85:name *= 'st'"];`

However I have found that if any window has a title that contains the letters `st` in it, then the transparency will apply to that window too.

Is there any way to get strict pattern matching in compton when applying opacity, so that opacity is only applied when the title of the window is exactly equal to `st`, rather than a string containing that substring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting rules with names, set them with classes.

Open an st window. In that, run `xprop`, and the cursor should change to a cross. Now, click anywhere inside the window, and `xprop` will return a somewhat substantial output. From the bottom, look for an attribute `WM_CLASS(STRING)` (or something like that). It will have two values, which will most likely differ only by case. The second one mostly works.

Then in the `compton.conf`, set rule as `opacity-rule = ["85:class_g = '$window_class'"]`, and replace `$window_class` by the class `xprop` returned.

Restart `compton` by `killall compton; compton &` and report!!

Comment: This worked as intended, thank you.